# What does P(Σ∗) mean in complexity theory?

Tags: complexity-theory, computer-science, theory

Anyone one knows what that P(Σ*) means? also known as SΣ.

- Σ is the set of symbols.
- Σ* is the set of all finite length strings over Σ.

I don't know how to start search for P(Σ*) without known what that is.

Comment: P is usually used to refer to polynomial time, but I've never seen it with an actual argument.  You might have better luck asking this on [cstheory.se].

Comment: @JB.- cstheory is more for research-level CS questions. This is probably a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com, which is a good place to ask more theoretical CS questions that aren't at the research level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, I believe that P refers to the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), the set of all subsets of a set. In this case, P(Σ*) means "the power set of Σ*." This is the set of all languages over Σ, since it contains all sets of strings made from characters in Σ.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If Σ={a,b}. Then Σ* is the set of all finite length string over Σ. So, Σ*={a,b,ab,aa,bb,aabb,aab,....} should be infinite long. What's the power sets of that?..Still a bit confused.

Comment: @geasssos- That's correct. Infinite sets can have power sets just like finite sets; it just happens to be infinitely large.

Comment: @geasssos The power set of `{a,b,ab,aa,bb,aabb,aab,....}` is `{{}, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {ab}, {a, ab}, {b, ab}, {a, b, ab} ...}`